# Open phone browser on connect to a Node Server

Tags: node.js, express, iptables, captivenetwork

I need a node middleware that advice cellphones that my app is a captive portal, all request are redirected to the Node(Express) server ip by iptables rules and the App works perfectly but the cellphone browser dont start on connect, i think is near this but it dont works:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  let sites = [
    'localhost:3000',
    'localhost',
    '10.0.0.1:3000',
    '10.0.0.1',
    '127.0.0.1',
    '127.0.0.1:3000'
  ];
  if (sites.indexOf(req.get('host')) === -1) {
    res.redirect(302, '10.0.0.1');
  }
});
```

I debug it and the requests to sites like "clients3.google.com/generate_204" and the others are captured and the redirect response is sended, so I think is something about headers or the redirect code but...

Or is there another way to do that easily (with IPtables or in /etc/resolv.conf...)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force the device to open its browser.  Not all devices do this... not all devices even detect the captive portal issue.